# Where to input the html, css and JS in a phonegap application?

Tags: cordova

So I have followed phones gaps [getting started guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) and have a running project in eclipse.

But this is java. So where do I input the html etc?

I can see none of these things inside of eclipse project I have created.

This is driving me up the wall as i know this can't be the case and I am missing something fundamental.

Comment: they should be under assets/www folder in your project

Comment: brilliant, thanks. Any tips on how on earth the edit the html within eclipse. In my mind, i just won't edit within and only use it to compile and test the app. What you think?

Comment: afaik, eclipse doesn't have built in html support. so you can only view them as text(right click -> open in -> text editor) no autocomplete, no highlighting, no auto indentation etc. but you can still use your favorite editor for editing html, and eclipse for compiling and running the phonegap app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**assets** directory, under your project.